# CiviCase: Accordions not toggle ("Roles" "Activities"). Menu Options ("Add Activity" etc.) not "auto-trigger," Admin menus at top of screen not open

Tags: civicase, menu

CiviCRM 4.6.8; Drupal 7.39

Everything seems normal when I go to the dashboard initially. I click "Manage" to open a previous case. On the case management page that follows, pretty much all menus and accordions are non-responsive.

Screenshot:
[image: Example of largely unresponsive Manage page.]

I recently created and installed a new Drupal Theme, but it all worked fine in the development and test environments, and the issue persists whether I'm in the new theme or the old theme (where it worked fine). However... I went back to my dev and test environments and it's failing now. What the hey? I tried clearing caches (CiviCRM and browser) and the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my problems stemmed from one module I installed to make adjusting the new theme easier: SwitchTheme. After installing the new theme, I installed SwitchTheme 7.x-1.x-dev on all environments. I was so caught up in theme-tweaking that when I spotted this CiviCase error, I'd forgotten about SwitchTheme. Additionally, it's such a tiny, minor module, I really hadn't expected it to have such a big impact on site behavior.

Disabling SwitchTheme 7.x-1.x-dev in Drupal's Modules page immediately resolved the issue.